What are the pins worn by the two detectives in the TV show, The Undoing?
In the TV show, The Undoing (2020), episode 1, two police detectives interview parents after one mother is found murdered.
They both wear an unique pin on their suits, looking like this:

I assume they represent “D”etectives? Do police detectives wear these pins in real life in New York?

Typo: "an unique" should be "a unique"

These are members of the NYPD Detectives Bureau. As you rightly say, the 'D' is for Detective.

The badge is in current usage, as you can see from this photo of the present Chief of Detectives, Joseph Kenny

